# Steps to deploy play framework application to production environment?

Tags: java, linux, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I got stuck in the steps to deploy the `play-java` application to standalone server. I am using `Ubuntu` instance running on`Ec2` machine. After reading the [official](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) documentation I followed these steps:

- Install `typesafe activator` to `$Home/activator`
- Copy my project folder to `$Home/activator/projects` using `Jenkins`
- Run `cd $Home/activator/projects/project`
- Run `dist` command. It generate the project sh file
- Run `cd $HOME/activator/projects/sample/target/universal`. It shows me three things i.e. `sample-1.0.zip` , `tmp`.
- Run `unzip sample-1.0.zip`
- Run `cd $Home/activator/sample/target/universal/sample-1.0/bin`. It shows me two scripts i.e. `sample` (for mac and linux) and `smaple.bat` (for windows).

Now, I tried to run this command as documentation says: `sample-1.0/bin/sample -Dplay.crypto.secret="abcdefghijk"` but it got stuck and shows nothing except a prompt on terminal.

What next steps are required to run the application in `daemon` mode. So that server will continue to run always?

Another question is why do I need to follow these steps because just after copying the project I can easily run `activator run` command to `sample` folder to run the server.

## EDIT-1

Now I am getting `Error: Could not find or load main class play.core.server.ProdServerStart` while running `sample -Dplay.crypto.secret="abcdefghijk"` command

Comment: what is the prompt on terminal?

Comment: Previously It was something else but now I am getting `Error: Could not find or load main class play.core.server.ProdServerStart` after running `sample -Dplay.crypto.secret="abcdefghijk"`. BTW I haven't mentioned crypto secret to my project anywhere

Comment: Would you please test this parameter ? -Dplay.crypto.secret=abcdefghijk (without "")

Comment: Same error "Could not find.."

Comment: I think I'm find the mistake. Don't cd in `$Home/activator/sample/target/universal/sample-1.0/bin`. cd in  `cd $Home/activator/` ) then run last command. Is it okay?

Comment: Wow! I think it's working now but it shows "Your application is updated". However I will fix it but what is the advantage of following these procedure when I can run simple this project through activator run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123989/discussion-between-saman-and-prerna-rawat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Play Framework modes

Play like other frameworks can run in different modes because we are usually like to run our program in different situation and these situations need their configuration. Production is one of play modes. In this mode as the name suggested we are ready to deploy our application where user can use.As a result requirements are different.

## Some common configuration in Production mode :

- We are confining https
- Using production data base not testing one
- Play doesn't show errors
- Play framework run as long term process and if you are log out of your server your application will run
- If your app fails Play will clone another application and run that so your app run forever except you turn it off.
- and so on (it is based on your Production config file)

### Your answer :

If you just want to test your app in remote server and see what happened, it's okay to use `activator run` this command runes Play app in development mode and application will killed if you exit or log off (error will shows up and so on). But if you want to use your app for Production it is necessary to run all of these steps.

Comment: To run it on background I use `screen` command and it works fine :)

Comment: Good idea. Thanks